# Equal heights different width layout for dynamic image gallery

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

am working on a codeigniter website and currently trying to achieve a layout like this where i have equal heights for all images in row but different widths.
[image]

My images are stored in a MYSQL database with url paths pointing to the directory where they are located. I have also stored their heights and widths (the height and widths are stored in pixels).

Here is the sql for fetching the contents in PhotoController

```
$data['data'] = $this->model 
  ->select('photo_path, photo_height, photo_width') 
  ->get() 
  ->getResultArray();
```

Then in Home view, here is what i have so far. (using bootstrap 4 for styling)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <img src="<?= base_url($row['photo_path']); ?>" class="img-lazy img-fluid">
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am stuck on what to do next here.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="masonry-with-columns-2">
  <?foreach ($data as $row){?>
  <div>
    img here
  </div>
  <?}?>
</div>
```

scss

```
// Within style tags in your html file
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
// SCSS
// Masonry layout horizontal
.masonry-with-columns-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  div {
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    background: #9B1B30;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 2rem;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through 36 {
    div:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      $h: (random(400) + 70) + px;
      width: $h;
    }
  }
}
```

Source https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/layout/masonry/

Comment: This doesn't seem to sort out the equal height issue as the images are being cut off. Also can it be made to show a maximum of only 3 and minimum 2 images per row.

Comment: Okay i have found this plugin called [jquery-match-height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). And it solves the unequal height issue.